# Cannot emphasize underscored words in listings

Tags: listings, emphasis, underscore

I declared an emphasis mode that underlines and colors words in red, as follows:

```
\lstset{columns=fullflexible,basicstyle=\vttfamily,emph={\color{red}\underline}}
```

However, when using it in a lstlisting block, emphasising "my_function" does not render it underscored and in red.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\lstset{
 language=C, 
 basicstyle=\ttfamily,
 emph={\color{red}\underline}
}

\begin{lstlisting}[emph={my\_function}]
 int my_function() {
 }
\end{lstlisting}
```

\end{document}

How can I fix this ? Thank you !

Comment: It would help us a lot to help you, if you would provide a minimum working example of fully compilable code illustrating your problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) AnaK! As said by @JMP, please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}` -- i.e. give us a so-called [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As specified in the [`listings` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf) (§2.8, p. 19), the (optional) `emph` option of `\lstset` is to define *what* to (automatically) emphasis, when the `emphstyle` option is for defining *how* to (automatically or manually as you're doing) emphasis.

So you just need to replace `emph` by `emphstyle`! (-:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\lstset{
 language=C, 
 basicstyle=\ttfamily,
 emphstyle={\color{red}\underline}
}

\begin{lstlisting}[emph={my\_function}]
 int my_function() {
 }
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! While compiling your example gives the expected result, I still cannot make my more complex one work...I am using:  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[variablett]{lmodern}

Comment: It's then likely another issue that needs another thread (-; But the code still compiles fine for me, even with the packages you mention.

Comment: So the same problem occurs if I declare:                                 moredelim=[is][\color{red}\bfseries\vttfamily]{@}{@} in the \lstdefinelanguage environment. The underscore appears longer again...Any ideas how to fix this ? Thanks !

Comment: this is a separate question, and you should thus ask it as a new one (but you add a link to this one if you want). You might thus be more likely to get a valid answer... and to help others! By the way, it is `\ttfamily` and not `\vttfamily`, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, my mistake. It stands for \newcommand*{\vttfamily}{%
  \fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{lmvtt}\selectfont
}